# Dumb questions around google container engine billing and accounting

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

The question moved here: https://serverfault.com/questions/724820/dumb-questions-around-google-container-engine
It's more appropriate on serverfault i think, and this removes any attempt of crosspost

Comment: I feel like you should split this into 3 questions at least, and I'm not sure all of them would be on topic.

Answer (score -1):

fwiw, Google Container Engine follows the same policies for billing as all Google Cloud Platform products.  Details can be found here:

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/4356087?hl=en

Comment: il you had followed the link, you would know that the google dos are not complete and that i have already read them.